# BT5.0 headset Haylou GT1 Plus microphone doesn't work on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, 20.04, bluetooth, microphone, headset

What is the pipeline to make microphone alive on Ubuntu? I have bured alive mic on my Acer Swift 3, which doesn't work on Ubuntu, so I need to use external mic on headset. I used some chineese noname headset, but lost power adaptor. Now I bought Haylou GT1 Plus. It works only as stereophones, but microphone doesn't work unboxed on Xubuntu. Only on Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've digged solution using **pipewire**:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pipewire-debian/pipewire-upstream
sudo apt update
sudo apt install pipewire
sudo apt install libspa-0.2-bluetooth
sudo apt install pipewire-audio-client-libraries

systemctl --user daemon-reload
systemctl --user --now disable pulseaudio.service pulseaudio.socket
systemctl --user mask pulseaudio
systemctl --user --now enable pipewire-media-session.service

systemctl --user restart pipewire
sudo reboot
```

It fixed general issue with audio on my laptop (now my builtin mic works too). And both bluetooth headsets *Haylou GT1 Plus* and *Mi True Wireless Earphones 2 Basic* works too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to solve it for two weeks. Somehow,

- after trying all of blueman/pavucontrol solutions
- close all background music
- connect to Haylou
- right click, Audio Profile: Choose immediately A2DP Sync, CODEC BSC.